# Ktor Client XML: Serialize Object Properties as XML Children

Tags: android, ktor

Is it possible to settup Ktor Client to Serialize Object Properties as XML Children?

```
<PersonDTOXML>
  <id>1</id>
  <name>John</name>
  <age>20</age>
</PersonDTOXML>
```

By default, Object Properties are serialized as XML Attributes.

```
<PersonDTOXML id="1" name="John" age="20" />
```

I was following tutorials at https://ktor.io/docs/serialization-client.html#receive_send_data

```
//==================================================================
// MAIN ACTIVITY
//==================================================================
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {

      var person by remember { mutableStateOf(PersonDTOXML(0, "No name", 0)) }
      val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

      Button(onClick = { coroutineScope.launch { person = callURL() } }) {
        Text("RESPONSE: $person")
      }

    }
  }
}

//==================================================================
// CALL URL
//==================================================================
suspend fun callURL() : PersonDTOXML {

  //CONFIGURE CLIENT
  val client = HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(ContentNegotiation){ xml() }
  }

  //CAL URL
  val person: PersonDTOXML = client.get("http://192.168.0.102:8080/ReceiveBodyXML").body()

  //CLOSE CLIENT
  client.close()

  //RETURN PERSON
  println(person)  //Person(id=1, name=John, age=20)
  return person;

}

//==================================================================
// PERSONDTOXML
//==================================================================
@Serializable
data class PersonDTOXML(val id: Int, val name: String, val age: Int)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate properties of the `PersonDTOXML` class with the `XmlElement` annotation to force them be serialized to XML elements:

```
@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
data class PersonDTOXML(@XmlElement(true) val id: Int, @XmlElement(true) val name: String, @XmlElement(true) val age: Int)
```

Also, you can write a [custom policy](https://github.com/pdvrieze/xmlutil#format) to redefine how the Kotlin structure is translated to XML.